# Observable implementation: undeclared functions

Tags: javascript, observable, es6-class

I followed a Medium post's tutorial and built an Observable and an Observer class. However, when tracing the code, I found two functions aren't declared, but the code works. Specifically,

1. `_unsubscribe()`
2. `this._subscribe(observer)`

I've tried the debugger with repl.it, but still cannot understand why. Am I missing something important regarding Javascript?

```
class Observer {
  #handlers;
  #isUnsubscribed;
  _unsubscribe; // whether the observer is unsubscribed

  constructor(handlers) {
    this.#handlers = handlers;
    this.#isUnsubscribed = false;
    this._unsubscribe = null;
  }

  next(value) {
    if (!this.#isUnsubscribed && this.#handlers.next) {
      this.#handlers.next(value);
    }
  }

  error(error) {
    if (!this.#isUnsubscribed && this.#handlers.error) {
      this.#handlers.error(error);
    }
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  complete() {
    if (!this.#isUnsubscribed && this.#handlers.complete) {
      this.#handlers.complete();
    }
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  unsubscribe() {
    this.#isUnsubscribed = true;
    if (this._unsubscribe) {
      // TODO: what is the "_unsubscribe()"?
      this._unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}

class Observable {
  _subscribe;

  constructor(subscribe) {
    this._subscribe = subscribe;
  }

  subscribe(obs) {
    const safeObserver = {
      next: obs.next || (() => { }),
      error: obs.error || (() => { }),
      complete: obs.complete || (() => { }),
    };

    const observer = new Observer(safeObserver);

    // TODO: what is the "this._subscribe(observer)", which is not declared
    observer._unsubscribe = this._subscribe(observer);

    return ({
      unsubscribe() {
        observer.unsubscribe();
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * return the observable from an array
   * @param {Number[]} values 
   * @returns 
   */
  static from(values) {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      values.forEach((v) => observer.next(v));
      observer.complete();

      // once unsubscribed, return a message
      return () => {
        console.log('unsubscribe');
      };
    });
  }
}

function init() {
  const numbers$ = Observable.from([0]);
  const subscription = numbers$.subscribe({
    next(value) { console.log(value); },
    error(err) { console.error(err); },
    complete() { console.info('done'); }
  });
  subscription.unsubscribe()
}

init();
```

Comment: What do you mean? `_unsubscribe` is declared right there, in the third line inside the `Observer` class. Every time it’s used, it is either _set_ to something or called; and before it is called, its [truthiness](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy) is checked (granted, that’s not a sufficient check if it’s callable). Why do you think any of these operations should fail? `_subscribe` is also declared at the top of the `Observable` class. Its value is set in the constructor; however this time there is no error handling whatsoever, so `new Observable().subscribe()` will throw.

Comment: See the MDN documentation about [public class fields](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields).

Comment: @SebastianSimon in the original implementation, it doesn't have the `_unsubscribe` declared inside the `Observer` class. Without the declaration, it still works. The second one is that `_subscribe` function takes an argument with it. It is different from `_subscribe` property, which the constructor takes and assigns. It comes out of nowhere and unsubscribes the observable. That's why I got confused.

Comment: But field declarations such as these are optional in classes. You can assign `this.whatever = 1;` or `numbers$.whatever = 1;`. If the property doesn’t exist, `this.whatever === undefined`.

Comment: yeah, that's why the code seems to be bouncing around, and I need clarification on how the code achieves the unsubscription. I am okay with `this.whaterever = 1`, adding a property to another class, but `observer._unsubscribe = this._subscribe(observer);` is so confusing.

Comment: This line calls `this._subscribe` with argument `observer` and assigns its result to `observer._unsubscribe`. If `this._subscribe` isn’t a function at the time of execution, this line will throw an error. Other than that, not much can fail here.

Comment: That's the point! Since I don't recognize where the function `this._subscribe` is situated inside the `Observable` class. It should fail, but it doesn't.

Comment: But it’s defined in the constructor: `this._subscribe = subscribe;`. Setting a property on the instance will just create a normal property on the instance or set the existing one to a new value. The constructor is called when `new Observable` is used.

Comment: okay, thank you @SebastianSimon. Let me think about it that `this._subscribe` is a property or a function.

Comment: Thank you @SebastianSimon. I understand now that both of them are `undefined` initially, but after, they are assigned a function.